# Delphi XE8 - IDE Fixe Pack failed on startup

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8

I upgraded to Windows 10. and when I start Delphi XE8 it shows the following dialog. I suppose it is to do with IDE Fix Pack but not sure how to get rid of it. The compiler still works.

[image]

Comment: You should be asking the author of IDEFixPack

Comment: You can ask the question on the [site](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/07/ide-fix-pack-dev-snapshot-supports-windows-10-insider-preview/) of IDEFixPack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [IDE Fix Pack 5.93](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/08/ide-fix-pack-5-93-windows-10-support/) fixes this issue with Windows 10.

Windows 10 uses INT3 instead of NOP to align a function that IDE Fix Pack wants to hook, but IDE Fix Pack expected NOPs.